# Custom EditTextPreference in android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, android-preferences

I create a `PreferenceActivity` in which there are two `EditTextpreferences`. Clicking on the preference it opens dialog with `EditText` and two `buttons`(**OK and Cancel**). I want to add `button` on the right side of the default `edittext` this `dialog` in `PreferenceActivity`. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a simple preference as follows.

```
<Preference
                android:title="Custom Preference"
                android:summary="This works almost like a button"
                android:key="customPref" />
```

> I want to add button on the right side
>   of the default edittext this dialog in
>   PreferenceActivity

On click of this preference you can open your custom dialog and in this dialog layout you can add your views.

Comment: but i want all edittextpreference functionality to EditText like store value in sharedpreference etc... If I make my custom layout with edittext , then how can I achieve functionality like edittextpreference.